# How to share the object of a class apart from AppDelegate class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

I know that we can easily use the objects declare in our appDelegate class by doing this

```
myAppDelegate *alpha= (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

hence from above we can use the alpha object to fetch the value of other objects in myAppDelegate class.

but suppose if I have a Class A and i have declared a NSString *hello in its .h and synthesize it in .m file.

Now in Class B I create an object of class A i.e

```
A *classA = [[A alloc]init];
A.hello = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kawa banga"];
[classA release];
```

Now in Class C I create an object of Class A again

```
 A *classA = [[A alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@",classA.hello);
```

It gives me null.

How can I get the value of my hello object in different class.

Comment: that class A is UIViewCOntroller class

Comment: Ok doesn't matter it can store id type object(s) with associated  key.Here key is provided by you just like NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `hello` as a property of class `A`, it’s an instance variable. That means it’s separate for each instance of `A` you create (with `alloc` & `init`).

It looks like you might want to share just 1 instance of `A`. An easy way of doing this is to add it as a property of your `myAppDelegate` class. (By the way, class names in Cocoa are usually begin with upper-case letter to distinguish them for variable names)

Once you’ve done that, you’ll be able to access it with:

```
myAppDelegate *alpha = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
myAppDelegate.classA.hello = @"hello, world";
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to use Singleton pattern or pass the object to the required class.

I think you need to go through on the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)